# Background Updates Not Happening

Tags: security, updates, wordpress-version, automatic-updates

I have some sites which are not updating with the background updater. I installed the Background Update Tester plugin and everything looks fine. Currently they are at 3.9 but they are telling me that 3.9.1 is available. Am I mistaken in thinking that the 3.9.1 update should be applied automatically?

Comment: Yes, your sites should be updating to 3.9.1. It could be that WP-Cron isn't functioning correctly on your site. Try installing the [WP Crontrol plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) and visiting its settings screen. It will tell you there if WP-Cron is failing.

Comment: Thanks ... I installed that. Didn't see anything amiss. What would it show if there was a problem. It was a list of hooks ... any of these I'd need to check in particular?

Comment: If it detected a problem it would show up as an error message above that list. So it sounds like WP-Cron is working as expected.

Comment: If you're seeing the issue on multiple sites, can you perform an update on one of the sites using the built-in updater, and let us know if it succeeds?

Comment: Yes I did that on one of the sites and it updated fine ... presumably this would be just to rule something out as a culprit because obviously it's the automatic aspect which is the problem.

Comment: My hosting company have been digging around and they seem to think it could be a plugin somewhere ... one that I have on all my sites ... so I'll set up a test blank install somewhere and just wait and see if it autoupdates when 3.9.2 comes out.

Comment: You could manually install 3.9 again somewhere and then it should auto-update to 3.9.1. Save you waiting for 3.9.2.

Comment: I know ... thanks. Probably have spent enough time on it already though.